# save data to database buttton not working commit vb.net

Tags: vb.net

commit button not working and does not give any errors and update gives an error
please help thanks in advance

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection ' THE CONNECTION OBJECT

Dim dbProvider As String ' HOLDS THE PROVIDER
Dim dbSource As String ' HOLDS THE DATA SOURCE
Dim MyDocumentsFolder As String ' HOLDS THE DOCUMENTS FOLDER
Dim TheDatabase As String ' HOLDS THE NAME OF THE DATABASE
Dim FullDatabasePath As String ' HOLDS THE DATABASE PATH
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer
Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
Dim sql As String
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Private Sub Commit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Commit.Click
    If inc <> -1 Then

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)


        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("student").NewRow()

        dsNewRow.Item("StudentID") = StudentIDTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Fullname") = FullnameTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Course") = CourseTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Email") = EmailTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Password") = PasswordTextBox.Text
        ds.Tables("student").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)


        da.Update(ds, "student")

        MessageBox.Show("New Record added to the Database")

        Commit.Enabled = False
        AddNew.Enabled = True
        btnUpdate.Enabled = True
        btnDelete.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't included the SQL query

Comment: First you say *"does not give any errors"* and then you say *"update gives an error"*.Which is it? If an exception is thrown then please provide the error message. If there is no exception then how EXACTLY are you determining that it's not working? Assuming that there is no exception, the very first thing to do is test the value returned by `Update`. If that's not zero then it's working as it should and the issue is that you're not checking for the changes properly, which is not uncommon.

Comment: no sorry about that i sent the commit code the commit code does nothing